# Program to learn languages

Tags: language

I am looking for an online site/program where I could refresh my french/english especially the french/english related to the hotel reception...

Do you maybe know such a site/program?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [DuoLingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) before, but it was a while back and not for very long so take this recommendation with a grain of salt. However, I have heard good things about it more recently from people I trust.

They use "gamification" to make learning addictive and fun, and they say they have [science](https://www.duolingo.com/effectiveness-study) to back up their teaching methods.

It's a general-purpose language-learning program, so maybe it's not precisely what you're looking for, but it seems to be worth mentioning.